# Send data to MainActivity from Service

Tags: java, service

I have a lookup service which calculates the latency of some servers. I want to write those in TextView but since there is no findviewbyid in Service i have to send those datas to main activity. Basicly i want to send an array to MainActivity from service. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to transfer data from one activity to another? So just use the startActivityForResult()
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result